# Regression analysis with range (instead of single value) as independent variable

Tags: multiple-regression, epidemiology

I would like to investigate the association between an exposure variable (an environmental pollutant) and a health endpoint using a regression model. This is usually done with a multi-linear model where y is the endpoint (a continuous variable, e.g. blood pressure), $x_1$ the exposure (e.g. air concentration of contaminant):

$y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 \times  x_1 +  \ldots$

The end-point data (y) are precise as they have been measured directly. However, it is not possible to obtain a precise measurement of exposure and the best we can obtain is a range (e.g 0.54 - 0.58 ppm).

The standard approach is to use the mean or maximum value, but this does not take the uncertainty into account.

Is it possible (and sensible) to use the range instead of a single value in a regression model, i.e.:

$y = \beta_0 + \beta_1 \times (x_{1_{min}} \cdots x_{1_{max}})  \ldots$

To illustrate, here are some sample data:

```
y     x_min     x_max     x_mean
139   0.2       0.8       0.5
136   0.1       0.3       0.2
142   0.5       1.3       0.9
148   0.4       0.8       0.6
134   0.1       0.5       0.3
```

(m_mean is the mean of x_min and x_max and often used as $x_1$).

Comment: Can you explain your question better or maybe give a little example of how is the data? I truly didn't understood what you need yet.

Comment: Your title refers to a "distribution" while the question refers to a "range": could you please clarify the nature of this quantity and how it is measured or obtained?

Comment: I have tried to make it clearer. The confusion of "range" and "distribution" resulted of an attempt to make a clearer question.