# Get a range of values (val_1 to val_2) instead of one value in linear regression

Tags: regression, linear-model, prediction-interval

So, the idea is that I use linear regression and I get an equation `y = a * x + b`. So when I give a value `x` I get a predicted value `y`. However, what I want to achieve is instead of a single value `y` to get a range of values, such as `[val_1 - val_2]`.Can this be done? Also I have found this question: [Regression analysis with range (instead of single value) as independent variable](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/310443/regression-analysis-with-range-instead-of-single-value-as-independent-variable) which did not help...

Comment: Can you explain what your `val_1` and `val_2` would be?

Comment: The values of the range: [```min``` to ```max```]...

Comment: Hm. Linear regression usually assumes normally distributed errors, which go from minus to plus infinity, and your regression will not tell you that there is a max value your $y$ *cannot* exceed, so the best you can do would be to always output $(-\infty,\infty)$. This is probably not helpful. Would a [tag:prediction-interval] work for you, i.e., an interval that contains the future realization with (say) 95% probability?

Comment: @Stephan Kolassa: If I calculate the ```MSE``` of my model and get the ```SD = sqrt(MSE)``` so a range: ```[y-SD, y+SD]``` ? Do we say the same thing?

Comment: Yes, that is a prediction interval. It will be too narrow, though, since it only includes one source of uncertainty, namely residual uncertainty - but not parameter uncertainty. Let me write up an answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you are looking for is a [prediction interval](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Prediction_interval), i.e., an interval $[a,b]$ such that a new observation falls within it with a certain prespecified probability, e.g., 95%. (Of course, there are multiple such intervals. The typical convention is to have "prediction interval" refer to a *symmetric* PI, such that $P(y<a)=P(y>b)=0.025$.)

You can find the formulas and explanation in [Faraday (2002)](https://cran.r-project.org/doc/contrib/Faraway-PRA.pdf), section 3.5. Note that Faraday calls PIs "confidence intervals for predictions", which I find unfortunate, because it risks confusion with "normal" confidence intervals, which pertain to unobservable parameters. [There is a difference between CIs and PIs.](https://stats.stackexchange.com/tags/prediction-interval/info)

Your favorite statistics package can probably give you prediction intervals. For instance, here is some toy data in R, and we calculate a central 95% PI at a IV of $x=0.7$:

```
set.seed(1)
xx <- runif(20)
yy <- 1+xx+rnorm(20)
model <- lm(yy~xx)
xx_pred <- 0.7
predict(model,newdata=data.frame(xx=xx_pred),interval="prediction",level=0.95)
#        fit        lwr      upr
# 1 1.527059 -0.4707293 3.524847
```

You will get a prediction of the expectation of $y$ of $1.53$, and a prediction interval of $(-0.47, 3.52)$.